# terminate current celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I'd like to write a method to cancel the current running celery task in a django application, I've tried a few different ways and I'm finding the documentation a bit confusing. I'm just looking for a simple example.

Comment: does it need to be in python ?

Comment: @josephmisiti preferably :)

Comment: if you know task id, you can directly terminate it

Comment: @ChillarAnand yea part of the trouble I've been having is finding the id of the currently running task

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of tasks, you can use

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
inspect().active()
```

This give a list of active tasks that are being processed. There you can get id of the task. Once you got the id of the task, you can revoke it by using this

```
from celery.task.control import revoke
revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

You can write a function to automate this.